# Sellenium in Python Basic

Tags: python, for-loop

Here's a Script That Catches Links on a 'X' Website Below:

CODE1:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Url=''
r=requests.get(Url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('div > a[href*="/view"]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    print(' \033[7;31;10mLINK \033[m')
    print('https://joao.com'+str(ref))
```

And I Did Another Part Downloading With Link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\\Downloads\chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/pt/youtube-converter')
al = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "OK"]')) )
al.click()

ak=browser.find_element_by_id('texturl')
ak.send_keys('')

au = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "Começar"]')) )
au.click()

af = WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'downloadq'))
)

browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', af)
```

How would you change the content within `*ak.send_keys*` for each Link that is Generated?

If Anyone Knows What I Do!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague. But if you're trying to loop through various links you could set those as a list variable. Then can iterate through each one using the value in your `send_keys` call.

```
links = ["www.linkeone.com", "www.linktwo.com", "www.linkthree.com"]

for link in links:
    browser=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\\Downloads\chromedriver')
    browser.get('https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/pt/youtube-converter')
    al = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until( 
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "OK"]')) )
    al.click()

    ak=browser.find_element_by_id('texturl')
    ak.send_keys(link)

    au = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "Começar"]')) )
    au.click()
    ...
```